# Managing execution priorities and request expiry time in your web application

Tags: web-applications, httpwebrequest

Some installations that run our applications can be under hefty stress on a busy day. Our clients ask us is there is a way to manage priorities in our application. For example, in a typical internet banking application, banks are interested in having the form “Transfer money” responsive, while the “Statement” page is a lot less critical. Not being able to transfer money is a direct loss for the bank, while not being able to produce a statement or something similar can be fixed with an apology. AFAIK, neither can you manage different request or session timeouts in a typical web application, it is one value for the whole of your web app.

Managing message priority and expiry time is a typical feature in many middleware platforms. Something like this can be useful for a web front end as well. Do any of web servers (either java or .net) or web frameworks provide these features? How would you go about implementing it if you’d have to go for roll-your-own?

Comment: Some of my questions are "open" questions. Also, isn't bounty automatically assigned even if the answer is not accepted by question creator?

Comment: Please see this meta article:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work-in-stackoverflow.  "The answer with the most votes is automatically accepted after 7 days. The bounty is subtracted from your reputation. The answerer is awarded half the bounty amount. If more than one answer is tied with most votes, the first answer receives the award."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty broad topic (which might also be appropriate for [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/)), and are a number of options to consider both within your application and in the platform and network environment under which it runs.  There are so many variables (e.g., CPU, memory, bandwidth and database access) to consider, it is nearly impossible to come up with a definitive answer based on your question.  But, here are some examples of strategies you might employ, both of which assume your application is stateless, and you can split its functionality into multiple parts either physically or virtually (isolating transactions from statements in your situation).  If these assumptions do not hold true, please clarify the question.

- You can achieve this behavior within
  IIS. You need to split the
  application into multiple sites (or
  do so virtually by creating multiple
  copies of the application).  A
  domain/subdomain model is ideal. 
  Your transactions might occur on
  www.mysite.com, while statements are
  generated on docs.mysite.com.  You
  can then [limit connections](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/38fb0130-b14b-48d5-a0a2-05ca131cf4f2.mspx?mfr=true) and
  [throttle bandwidth](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/38fb0130-b14b-48d5-a0a2-05ca131cf4f2.mspx?mfr=true) on the lower
  priority application.  If you are
  using ASP.NET, you can also [restrict
  the lower priority app to specific
  CPU cores](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;815156) while leaving the other unrestricted.
- Since you are dealing with a high
  volume application, you are likely
  using a load balancer to spread
  traffic across multiple web servers.  If your application is truly
  stateless (that is, no use of nasty
  session variables, etc.), you can
  likely take advantage of your load
  balancer to perform the traffic
  prioritization for you in one or more
  ways.  For example, let's say you
  have N front end web servers (where N > 2).  You
  could run two separate pools in the
  load balancer to spread the load for
  transactions over 2/3 of them and
  statements over the other 1/3 with
  failover configured between them.  (Depending on your load balancer, you may be able to do this based on path or HTTP header, as examples, even without splitting up your app.)
  This gives you both fault tolerance
  and prioritization.  There are other
  choices depending on the load
  balancer employed, but hopefully this
  is enough to spark your interest in
  moving the problem to infrastructure
  and not just stay within the walls of
  the application server.

Answer (score 0):

Coldfusion allows setting of request timeout on a per-request basis.

Apache allows setting expires header based on arbitrary conditions (like the URL visited).

You can run more than one webserver and set different CPU priority for each, or a load balanced cluster with more nodes for a given application than general use nodes.

To roll your own would be simple provided you know how to set thread priorities and some basic HTTP header stuff (like Expires).

You'll get a better answer if you're less vague. You ask if this can be done in .net or java yet you talk about your application like it is already written, so which is it written in, .net or java? You can hardly assume a solution for one will be applicable to the other or are we to assume you're going to rewrite your whole application? What web server are you using, that's equally relevant to the question?

Have you considered just buying more resources? For the cost of implementing and maintaining your priority schemes you could probably buy enough extra resources to make it redundant. Unless you're getting slahdotted every second day you should always have enough resources to handle at least twice your peak load or you're simply asking for trouble.

Comment: We build applications in J2EE. These are banking applications and they typically peak once a month (when people get paid). It would be a huge investment in hardware to try to cover those busiest days, where demand can go as much as 10* compared to an average day.

Comment: It still sounds like a reasonable investment. If my bank website kicked me off repeatedly while I'm checking my statement I wouldn't think too highly of that bank. Your question could be written as "What is the best way to deny service to most of our customers?"